# Average Interest Payment For Specific Period of Ammortization Schedule

Tags: finance

I would like to derive an equation that calculates the average interest payment `x` for an amortized mortgage loan in the first `m` months of the loan. Call the interest rate `i` and the principal `p` and the number of months `n`.

I understand the amortization equation shown in this wikipedia article and I understand how to calculate an amortization table by hand, but I do not no where to begin to derive the equation I am describing.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortization_calculator

I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could point me in the right direction. Thanks!